# Add a phrase to an existing algorithmic command/environment

Tags: environments, algorithms

I would like to add a new command to an existing environment. The `\renewenvironment` command does not help a lot since I need to copy and paste the entire environment definition.

For an example I would like to make a `\FORALL_P` for the `algorithmic` environment such that instead of producing

```
forall ... do
```

as original `\FORALL`, it produces

```
forall ... do in parallel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\algorithmicdoinparallel}{\textbf{do in parallel}}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{%
  \newcommand{\FORALLP}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ #2\ %
    \algorithmicdoinparallel\ALC@com{#1}\begin{ALC@for}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The definition of `\FORALLP` is modeled on that of `\FORALL`; you can't call it `\FORALL_P`, however.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do this but failed, \makeatletter does the magic...

Answer (score 9):

The [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package offers you some commands that could be useful, for example:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}
\AtEndEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}
```

Perhaps if you give us some mor information about your actual intent, we could provide more helpful information.

Now that new information has been provided in the question, I would suggest to use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package to define the new block; while the `algorithmic` package doesn’t allow you to easily modify predefined structures, or to create new ones, the `algorithmicx` package gives you full control over the definitions. Using `algcompatible`, you can have full compatibility with the syntax of the `algorithmic` package; a little example of the definition of the new block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\algblockdefx{FORALLP}{ENDFAP}[1]%
  {\textbf{for all }#1 \textbf{do in parallel}}%
  {\textbf{end for}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A test algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FORALL {$v \in V(G)$}
\STATE $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\ENDFOR
\FORALLP{$v \in V(G)$}
\STATE $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\ENDFAP
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the `\RETURN` command as defined by `algorithmic`, you need to add the following definition:

```
\algloopdefx{RETURN}[1][]{\textbf{return} #1}
```

Comment: thanks, I will look into etoolbox. I also added more info to my original post.

Comment: @iKid: please see my updated answer.

Comment: I failed to use the algorithmicx as they do not support \return ?

Comment: @iKid: I've added the corresponding definition.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I think I would stick with the etoolbox solution for the moment as many thing fail after I switch to algorithmicx.

Comment: @iKid: no problem. In fact, I thought that there was full compatibility (as `algorithmicx` advertises), but apparently it's not so "full".

Comment: How can I omit the "end for" at the end of the block?

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa `\usepackage[noend]{algcompatible}` for the standard `\FORALL`; if you need this for the new block, please feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, using commands of the `etoolbox` package to change the look of the \FORALL statement might not work because you're trying to change the subsequent statement, viz. "do..."

The `algorithmic` package allows for a fair bit of customization of various algorithm-like statements. For example, you could issue the command

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{do in parallel}}
```

However, this will change the output of the "do" statement in all instances, which may not be to your liking.