# "for all ... do in parallel" without "end for"

Tags: algorithmicx

I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34109/31969) approach to have a `for all ... do in parallel` using the `algcompatible` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\algblockdefx{FORALLP}{ENDFAP}[1]%
  {\textbf{for all }#1 \textbf{do in parallel}}%
  {\textbf{end for}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A test algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FORALL {$v \in V(G)$}
\STATE $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\ENDFOR
\FORALLP{$v \in V(G)$}
\STATE $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\ENDFAP
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

How can I  get rid of the `end for` at the end of the block?

Comment: I've added a MWE

Comment: You probably want to remove also the “end for” in the `\FORALL` cycle. Note that `algcompatible` is just for old documents and `algpseudocode` should be used instead.

Comment: Use `\algtext*{ENDFAP}` after defining `FORALLP` and `ENDFAP`, as suggested in [`algpseudocode` without end block text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764).

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa: Since the answer is entirely contained in the linked post, this could be considered a duplicate (rather up-vote the linked posts).